# Call function into an Array structure

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm trying to generate an array from a function in typescript.
My array looks like this:

```
model = {
  roles: { 4: true }
};
```

i need to change the values 4 with a function that generate values automatically. 
My function looks like this:

```
getIndex(data) {
  data.forEach(function (value) {
    return value['id'];
  });
}
```

i tried something like this but it didn't work and i have an error:

```
model = {
  roles: { getIndex(dataValues): true }
};
```

i want my array to looks like this from my function

```
model = {
  roles: { 4: true, 5: true, 7: false }
};
```

can anyone help me with that? thank you in advance guys ^^

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough information to be answered. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] of your issue (in a snippet should be enough)

Comment: Assume that if you don't reproduce the issue, then we won't be able to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **let model = {roles: {}};** is an object and not an array. You can refer the following code to get what you need.

```
const data = [{ id: 4, value: 'Potato' }, { id: 1, value: 'Tomato' }]

let model = {
    roles: {}
};

function getIndex(entity) {
    console.log(entity.value); /** Potato, Tomato  */
    return entity.id;
};

data.forEach(function (entity) {
    model.roles[getIndex(entity)] = true;
});

console.log(model);
```

Comment: thank you for your help. i forgot about the model.roles way to call object. i'm a begginer in typescript thats why. thank you